# nvarchar(max) on Linq to SQL receiving less characters on SQL when inserting

Tags: sql-server

While doing an `InsertOnSubmit` with Linq to SQL of a big string (70341 characters) into an `nvarchar(max)` on SQL, it is only inserting 46632 characters on SQL. I have already checked on the mapping the `DbType="nvarchar(max)"`, but I still get the string cut short, any thoughts?

Comment: perhaps there is some error going on and the data is being truncated.. are you sure that you are looking at the correct database table can you show the schema of the datafield and it's actual type also what happens if you try to run the Insert statement manually outside of LinqToSql in Sql Enterprise Manager..?

Comment: Does it always fail at same number of characters?  Are you sure your string contains 70341 characters?  What is the source of the string?  The string may be getting truncated due to the encoding you are using.

Comment: Yes I am looking to the correct database, the datatype of this field is nvarchar(max), also I check that the full message is complete with the 70341 characters just before the InsertOnSubmit and after that as well, so its definitely happening at the insert. Also I did inserted successfully the data manually from the SQL management studio.

Comment: Yes it fails at the same place every time at 46632 characters, and the string has 70341 just before the insert.

Comment: CORRECTION: when I tried to insert it manually on the SQL enterprise manager it only inserted 43679 characters out of the 70341, but the field is nvarchar(max), what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So, I find out that SQL Server was cutting the string short, because it has a maximum display of around 40k characters, however it was storing successfully the complete varchar, if you have the same issue you may want to use the following sp to display the full varchar:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Print_NVarcharMax]
(

@piStatement NVARCHAR(MAX))

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN
    -- This will mark the end of the SUBSTRING to pull (line being read).
    DECLARE @vCurrentEnd [BIGINT]

    -- This will be mark the offset used with the end of the current line being read.
    DECLARE @vOffset [TINYINT]

    -- Replace the CRLF to LF
    SET @piStatement = REPLACE(@piStatement, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), CHAR(10))

    -- Replace the CR with LF
    SET @piStatement = REPLACE(@piStatement, CHAR(13), CHAR(10))

    WHILE(LEN(@piStatement) > 1)
    BEGIN

        -- If we find a Line Feed (LF) in the first 4000 chars
        IF(CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @piStatement) BETWEEN 1 AND 4000)
        BEGIN

            -- Prints until the LF is found.
            SET @vCurrentEnd =   CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @piStatement) - 1
            SET @vOffset     =   2

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            -- Prints the entire line up to 4000 chars
            SET @vCurrentEnd    = 4000
            SET @vOffset        = 1

        END   

        -- Prints based on the delimiters.
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@piStatement, 1, @vCurrentEnd) 

        -- Removes what was printed and starts past the offset.
        SET @piStatement = SUBSTRING(@piStatement, @vCurrentEnd + @vOffset, LEN(@piStatement))   
    END 
END
```